# Change DIV vertical position in smaller resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, footer, floating

I need help. I have div as footer but without fixed position. So if I scrolling down footer scrolling too. But if I reduce size of my explorer footer has got wrong vertical position. So if the resolution of explorer is smaller I need to change vertical position.

Here is an example

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
MENU
</div>
<div id="content1">
something
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
<div id="content2">
something
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
width: 500px;
height: 20px;
background: blue;
position: fixed;
}

#content1 {
width: 500px;
height: 560px;
background: grey;
}

#footer {
width: 700px;
height: 40px;
    background: red;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.5;
bottom: -20px;
}

#content2 {
width: 500px;
height: 560px;
background: green;
}
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiriranc/w89Yc/3/

Do you see? If the size of resolution is big so footer overlap divs. But if the resolution is smaller div doesn't overlap and I need this overlap.

Comment: Please change your something in something else in the footer. One cannot see where the footer starts!

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

```
#header {
width: 500px;
height: 20px;
background: blue;
position: fixed;
}

#content1 {
width: 500px;
height: 560px;
background: grey;
}

#footer {
width: 700px;
height: 40px;
background: red;
bottom: -20px;
position:dynamic;
}

#content2 {
width: 500px;
height: 560px;
background: green;
}
```

and take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/w89Yc/4/

Comment: Yes. This is good. But I need absolute position, because DIV must work with javascript function animate and if I use position dynamic, animate script doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. My experiences with english are small.

Comment: Thank you. If you will need files of website, where is problem, I can post to you.

Comment: No matter. Thanks for your help :)